# Как сделать конкретную часть строки цветной?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Помогите мне пожалуйста. Как сделать так чтобы вторая часть строки в CMD тоже была зеленой?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Пронумеруйте для нас, пожалуйста, части строк. Какая часть строки первая, а какая - вторая?

Comment: Извините, не верно сформулировал вопрос. Я имел ввиду строки CMD. Перва сотня зеленая и вторая должна быть зеленая

Comment: С чем проблемы? У вас же в коде все есть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("Ваш доход: = ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
Console.WriteLine(debit);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, Игорь! А возможно ли сделать в одной строчке? Задать например переменную, объявить ей цвет и как-то использовать? Если да, то буду очень рад если объясните

Comment: @user302914 Нет, если Вам нужны разные цвета в одной строке, то выводить эту строку придется по частям.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое!